# Mounting virtual shared folder - mount succeeds, but any access to folders hangs

Tags: mount, bash, virtualbox, filesystem

I have been using the following script to mount virtual box shared drives in my guest Ubuntu (with host Windows)

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Mounts all known drives shared via virtual box

    # configuration
    MOUNT_POINT="${HOME}/media"
    MOUNT_DIRS="foo bar baz"
    USERID=$( id -u )
    GROUPID=$( id -g )

    for DIR in ${MOUNT_DIRS} ;  do
        mkdir -p ${MOUNT_POINT}/${DIR}
        sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=${USERID},gid=${GROUPID} ${DIR} ${MOUNT_POINT}/${DIR}
    done
```

This has served me well until a recent upgrade of the Linux kernel, to `3.11.0-24`,
after which this occurred.

Now this script succeed when run, mounting occurs without hitch.
However any form of access to the folder results in an indefinitely long wait.

`ls ~/media` works fine, but `ls ~/media/foo` hangs indefinitely, doing nothing.

What can I try or further diagnose to fix this problem?

---

System details:

```
$ uname -a && lsb_release -a
Linux brendang-linux 3.11.0-24-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 20:36:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

Comment: @Takkat nope - I was not aware that I need to do that (or even how)!

Answer (score 1):

As @Takkat suggests, reinstall guest addtions after the kernel update

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
sudo shutdown -r now
```

.. then restart the VM.

Now after running the script, the mount point succeeds.

Ensure that you have `dkms` installed.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Comment: @ Takkat I see your edit, unfortunately, however, I do not think it is accurate. Having `dkms` installed is indeed a pre-requisite for reinstallation of virtualbox guest additions to work. However, having it installed *does not* avoid having to reinstall guest additions after each kernel update. In fact I already had `dkms` installed and up to date, and I still needed to run this command manually.